# Wordpress Site Header Width (Genesis, Foodie Pro)

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm working on my blog: [livingthelighterlife.com](http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/)

And I'm having issues getting the header to look the way I want it to. I'd like the section in blue to be full width (as it currently is) but I want the actual header (the logo and navigation) to be the same width as the rest of the content (1040px) - hope this makes sense.

Not sure what coding I need to provide, but here's some to start:

```css
/*
Site Header
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */


.foodie-pro .site-header {
 background-color: #0099CC !important;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}

.genesis-header {
 background-color: #000000 !important;
}

.foodie-pro .site-header {

 background-position: left;
 margin-top: 30px;
}

.title-area {
 width: 450px;
}

.header-image .title-area {
 padding: 0;
}

.title-area h1 {
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.title-area p {
 margin: 0;
}

/* Full width header, no widgets */

.header-full-width .title-area,
.header-full-width .site-title {
 width: 100%;
}

.header-image .site-description,
.header-image .site-title a {
 display: block;
 text-indent: -9999px;
}

/* Logo, hide text */

.header-image .site-header {
 background-size: 450px 177px !important;
}

.header-image .site-title a {
 float: none;
 min-height: 177px;
 width: 450px;
}

/*
Site Navigation
----------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

/* Main Navigation
--------------------------------------------- */

.genesis-nav-menu .menu-item {
 display: inline-block;
}

.genesis-nav-menu {
 margin-top: -118px;
}

.genesis-nav-menu:before {
 content: "BROWSE RECIPES:";
 color: #f68364;
 font-size: 11.5px;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 margin-right: 5px;
}

.genesis-nav-menu {
 text-align: right;
 font-size: 11.5px;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.genesis-nav-menu a {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 padding-left: 5px;
 padding-right: 8px;
 color: #636367;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 transition: all 0s ease !important;
}

.genesis-nav-menu a:hover {
 color: #6dbea2;
}

li#menu-item-150 a {
 pointer-events: none;
 cursor: default;
 padding-left: 0px;
 padding-right: 3px;
 color: #f68364;
}

.menu-item:last-child a {
 padding-right: 0px;
}


li#menu-item-119:after, li#menu-item-120:after, li#menu-item-121:after {
 display: inline-block;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 content: "/";
 color: #b9b9b9;
}

/* Sub Navigation
--------------------------------------------- */

.menu-primary li{
 position: relative;
}

.genesis-nav-menu .menu-item:hover > .sub-menu,
.genesis-nav-menu .menu-item:focus > .sub-menu,
.genesis-nav-menu .menu-item.menu-item-hover > .sub-menu  {
 left: 50%;
 transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.genesis-nav-menu .sub-menu:before {
 content: '';
 display: block;
 margin: auto;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-left: 5px solid transparent;
 border-right: 5px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 5px solid #7b7c80;
}

.genesis-nav-menu .sub-menu {
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 z-index: 2000;
 left: -9999px;
 width: 100px;
}

.genesis-nav-menu .sub-menu a {
 width: 100px;
 padding: 10px;
 background-color: #7b7c80;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-size: 10px;
 text-align: center;
}

.genesis-nav-menu .sub-menu a:hover {
 background-color: #f78f73;
}
```

```html
<header class="site-header" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WPHeader"><div class="wrap"><div class="title-area"><h1 class="site-title" itemprop="headline"><a href="http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/">Living the Lighter Life</a></h1><p class="site-description" itemprop="description">Eat Clean. Train Hard. Live Lighter.</p></div></div></header><h2 class="screen-reader-text">Main navigation</h2><nav class="nav-primary" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="genesis-nav-primary" aria-label="Main navigation"><div class="wrap"><ul id="menu-main" class="menu genesis-nav-menu menu-primary"><li id="menu-item-119" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-119"><a href="http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Breakfast</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
 <li id="menu-item-151" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-151"><a href="http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/recipes/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Recipes</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-120" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-120"><a href="http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Lunch</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
 <li id="menu-item-156" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-156"><a href="http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/recipes-new__trashed-2/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Recipes NEW</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-121" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-121"><a href="http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Dinner</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
 <li id="menu-item-160" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-160"><a href="http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Coming Soon</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-148" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-148"><a href="http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Other</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
 <li id="menu-item-124" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-124"><a href="http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Desserts</span></a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-122" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-122"><a href="http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Snacks</span></a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-123" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-123"><a href="http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Sides</span></a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-125" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-125"><a href="http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Beverages</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-150" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-150"><a itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">•</span></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-25" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-25"><a href="http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Nutrition &#038; Fitness</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
 <li id="menu-item-126" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-126"><a href="http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Philosophy</span></a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-26" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-26"><a href="http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/sample-page/" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Workouts</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul></div></nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

That header image is probably in your WP settings. So, in order to make it simple, just wrap your header with a section:

```
<section class="my-header">
    <header class="site-header">
        ...
    </header>
</section>
```

Than add a couple of styles:

```
.my-header {
    background: none #0099CC;
}
.site-header {
    max-width: 1040px;
    /* It already has margins left and right set to "auto" */
}
```

Comment: How would I wrap? I'm very new to WP.